# English: looking for a common phrase that means "solving one problem yet causing another"

Tags: phrases

looking for a common phrase that means "solving one problem yet causing another"

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/388189/50044, https://english.stackexchange.com/q/333211/50044, https://english.stackexchange.com/q/31867/50044, and others

Comment: Out of the frying pan, into the fire.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proverb for: solving a problem creates a bigger one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388189/proverb-for-solving-a-problem-creates-a-bigger-one)

Comment: @1006a I object to the duplicate status on the grounds that the proposed duplicate requests a phrase for a problem a problem that is necessarily worse. "Causing yet another problem" can include that, but there is a subtle distinction in that it may also refer to a problem of equal stature, or perhaps even a lesser problem, so answers without that additional signification would be more ideal.

Comment: @Tonepoet If none of the suggestions given at that question (or the others mentioned by NVZ) suit this OP, then that should be explained in the question. Otherwise, even if it's theoretically marginally different, the question should be put on hold for lack of research.

Comment: @1006a Actually, I don't think that either because we usually don't close the request questions for lack of research either, since they can't normally be answered by commonly available resources. That is not to say it should not be put on hold, but if it is, I think the right reason should be applied. I think the "ideal word or phrase" close reason is the best one, since this question does not include an exemplary context or any other information regarding how it will be used to help us choose the best answer. Hopefully Christi can edit that information in before that becomes necessary though.

Comment: @Tonepoet There may be differences, which is why I merely left those as possible duplicates instead of actually voting to close. I did not find the time to scan thru the linked ones to see the differences.

Comment: Are you looking for colloquialism?  Consider the expression "Playing Whack-a-mole."

Answer (score 1):

*Unintended consequence* is defined as the unexpected result of taking some positive action to implement change, with one of the following three scenarios:

1. The initial problem is solved, while yielding an unanticipated benefit, described as a windfall.
2. The initial problem is solved but there is an unanticipated consequence that results in an unforeseen negative event.
3. The worst situation is a perverse outcome, when the action doesn't solve the original problem at all, but actually makes it worse instead.

Solving one problem but causing another one is the second scenario. The initial problem does get solved, but a new problem arises as a result. [These are some examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unintended_consequences#Unexpected_drawbacks) of unintended consequences.

Phrases for this situation are "law of unintended consequences", "unintended consequence" or "drawback".