# English equivalent phrase for "If left free, it runs and if leashed, it bites"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

Is there equivalent of this Marathi expression

> sodala (release) ki (then) palato (runs) pakala (kept caught) ki (then) chavto (bites)

which means

> (if a dog is) set free (it) runs away (and if) leashed (it comes) to bite (you).

Which means you cannot do either of the two with a person who has such crazy personality. This is applicable to bad situation too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Damned if you do, damned if you don’t](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/damned+if+you+do%2C+damned+if+you+don%27t)

Although this idiom doesn’t specifically describe a person (or dog), it does relate to the leash in your idiom. In short, the owner is damned if (s)he leashes the dog and equally misfortunate if (s)he doesn’t.

Comment: I had written this answer, and then deleted it because I then saw the bit about "you cannot do either of the two with a person with that kind of crazy personality."I thought the OP wanted something to describe also an unstable or unpredictable person.

Answer (score 1):

I always say they're [untrainable](https://thebark.com/content/untrainable-breeds).

- I like him, but he's **untrainable**.

Synonyms: [unmanageable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/unmanageable), [uncontrollable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/uncontrollable).

> out of control, ungovernable, wild, unruly, disorderly, recalcitrant, refractory, obstreperous, turbulent, intractable, incorrigible, disobedient, delinquent, insubordinate, defiant, non-compliant, undisciplined

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to decide between two options, both of which are bad,
you are [***between the devil and the deep blue sea***.](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/between-the-devil-and-the-deep-blue-sea.html)

The [Wikipedia entry for “between the devil and the deep blue sea”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_the_devil_and_the_deep_blue_sea)
mentions an alternative, ***[“between a rock and a hard place”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/between_a_rock_and_a_hard_place)***. 
(See also [The Free Dictionary’s entry](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/between+the+devil+and+the+deep+blue+sea).) 
The [Wiktionary entry for “between a rock and a hard place”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/between_a_rock_and_a_hard_place)
mentions ***[“[be] on the horns of a dilemma”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be_on_the_horns_of_a_dilemma#English)*** and others.

There is [a song titled “Between the Devil and the Deep Blue Sea”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_the_Devil_and_the_Deep_Blue_Sea_(song)),
whose [lyrics](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/h/harold+arlen/between+the+devil+the+deep+blue+sea_20064332.html) begin,

> I don’t want you
>   But I hate to lose you
>   You’ve got me in between
>   The devil and the deep blue sea

Answer (score 1):

If you have taken an action in order to fix a problem
(e.g., releasing the dog so it will stop biting you),
but you have created or encountered a new problem
(especially a worse one) as a result (e.g., the dog runs away),
you have *jumped **[out of the frying pan into the fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_frying_pan_into_the_fire)**.* 
Discussed at [the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/out-of-the-frying-pan-into-the-fire) and [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+the+frying+pan+into+the+fire).

See also ***[“The cure is worse than the disease.”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_cure_is_worse_than_the_disease)***

Related EL&U questions:

- [Are there any expressions that describe
  going from a bad to a worse situation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/31867/26083)
- [What is the problem that gets worse
  after you try to solve it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/333211/26083) (only loosely related)